# Return a string when return type is a ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Is it possible to return a string when my action is returning a ModelAndView?

```
public ModelAndView register(....) {

   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(...);


   if( // some wierd case) {
         // halt and return a string response
   }


   return mav;
}
```

This isn't for a normal case, I know I should redirect to another page and display some sort of message, but this is a unusual case where I don't really want to do that or at least I want to know if I have this option to do this.

Comment: What do you expect spring to do with the string?  Redirect to it?  Treat it as responsebody ? (Aside, typing "spring" and "string" in the same sentence is surprisingly difficult)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem?

Comment: I want to add my own text String within ModelAndView and display that?

Answer (score 1):

I would throw an Exception.  You can create a subclass of Exception for this case - a subclass that can hold and answer a string.  In this way you can return a String in special situations, but answer a ModelAndView most other times.

```
public ModelAndView register(....) throws WierdCaseException {

   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(...);


   if( // some wierd case) {
         // halt and return a string response
         throw new WierdCaseException("the string to be returned");
   }


   return mav;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotation `@ResponseBody` on your method.

Comment: But normallyI want to display using ModelAndView, how can I put responsebody in this case??

Comment: @Blankman How about calling another method using Ajax and return `String`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning a ModelAndView, are you populating your view with values on the server side.  Can you return the string as part of the ModelAndView?

```
mav.addObject("myString", "this is the string for the weird case");
```

Other option is to get the HttpServletResponse object's PrintWriter or ServletOutputStream and write the string out and then return a null ModelAndView.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention return type as String rather than ModelAndView. returned string name should be a name of jsp file.